# Importing data as list from text files

Tags: python, list, text

This seems like a simple problem, but I've looked online and can't find anything so here we go...

I have a text file with this information:

```
[['AX34 GFV','Name: John Smith1, Address: x, Number: x'],['AX34 ABC','Name: John Smith2, Address: x, Number: x'],['UH23 HUH','Name: John Smith3, Address: x, Number: x'],['ER54 SDR','Name: John Smith4, Address: x, Number: x'],['FE54 VMR','Name: John Smith5, Address: x, Number: x'],['23FX SDA','Name: John Smith6, Address: x, Number: x'],['AS23 JAS','Name: John Smith7, Address: x, Number: x']]
```

All I want to do is read this data, and it for be imported as a list, rather than a string. At the moment, this is what I have...

```
details = open("details.txt","r")
details = details.read()
details = list(details)
print(details)
```

But this takes each letter of the data, and produces it as a list...Any simple function to combat this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = "[['AX34 GFV','Name: John Smith1, Address: x, Number: x'],['AX34 ABC','Name: John Smith2, Address: x, Number: x'],['UH23 HUH','Name: John Smith3, Address: x, Number: x'],['ER54 SDR','Name: John Smith4, Address: x, Number: x'],['FE54 VMR','Name: John Smith5, Address: x, Number: x'],['23FX SDA','Name: John Smith6, Address: x, Number: x'],['AS23 JAS','Name: John Smith7, Address: x, Number: x']]  "
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
[['AX34 GFV', 'Name: John Smith1, Address: x, Number: x'], ['AX34 ABC', 'Name: John Smith2, Address: x, Number: x'], ['UH23 HUH', 'Name: John Smith3, Address: x, Number: x'], ['ER54 SDR', 'Name: John Smith4, Address: x, Number: x'], ['FE54 VMR', 'Name: John Smith5, Address: x, Number: x'], ['23FX SDA', 'Name: John Smith6, Address: x, Number: x'], ['AS23 JAS', 'Name: John Smith7, Address: x, Number: x']]
```

[ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal%5Feval)

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
list = []
details = open("details.txt", "r")
line = details.readline()
while(line != ''):
    list.append(line)
    line = details.readline()

print(list)
details.close()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I wasn't quite sure how to format it...I'll be sure to approve the answer when I can :P

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if this is really just a line or seperate lines.

But try .append()

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python code (like this list) as a string you can run it trhough the eval function:

```
>>> eval('[1, "2"]')
[1, '2']
```

It will return the evaluated Python expression.
But be careful this way code in the file will be executed. Make sure there is no unsafe user data!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
details = open("details.txt","r")
details = eval(details.read())
print(details)
```